# getting ajax to update corresponding div in mySQL row results

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have this AJAX code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateAssigned(assigned , ticketid)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
 {
document.getElementByID('origassigned').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
} 
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_php/assigned.php?assigned=" + assigned + "&ticketid=" + ticketid,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

And this HTML

```
<DIV CLASS="assigned">
  <DIV ID="origassigned"></DIV>
  <SELECT onChange="updateAssigned(this.value , {$row['ticket']})">
       <option>OPTION 1</option>
       <option>OPTION 2</option>
  </SELECT>
</DIV>

<DIV CLASS="assigned">
  <DIV ID="origassigned"></DIV>
  <SELECT onChange="updateAssigned(this.value , {$row['ticket']})">
       <option>OPTION 1</option>
       <option>OPTION 2</option>
  </SELECT>
</DIV>

<DIV CLASS="assigned">
  <DIV ID="origassigned"></DIV>
  <SELECT onChange="updateAssigned(this.value , {$row['ticket']})">
       <option>OPTION 1</option>
       <option>OPTION 2</option>
  </SELECT>
</DIV>
```

I cannot get AJAX to update the corresponding DIV. It works perfectly updating my database but Only changes the 1st DIV named "assigned" even if I'm updating the second DIV.

Any Ideas what I should change my AJAX code to so that it recognizes which DIV to update? Thanks!

UPDATE: Changed divs to not have same IDs to be more web compliant. Still don't know how to tell AJAX which div to update.
Sidenote: These are generated from a mySQL query result. Each grouping is a different row.  but they all come from same template. So the NAMEs CLASSes and IDs have to be the same on each group.

```
<DIV CLASS="assigned">
<DIV CLASS="origassigned" NAME="origassigned"></DIV>
<SELECT onChange="updateAssigned(this.value , {$row['ticket']})">
   <option>OPTION 1</option>
   <option>OPTION 2</option>
</SELECT>
</DIV>

<DIV CLASS="assigned">
<DIV CLASS="origassigned" NAME="origassigned"></DIV>
<SELECT onChange="updateAssigned(this.value , {$row['ticket']})">
   <option>OPTION 1</option>
   <option>OPTION 2</option>
</SELECT>
</DIV>

<DIV CLASS="assigned">
<DIV CLASS="origassigned" NAME="origassigned"></DIV>
<SELECT onChange="updateAssigned(this.value , {$row['ticket']})">
   <option>OPTION 1</option>
   <option>OPTION 2</option>
</SELECT>
</DIV>
```

Comment: Can you show the actual HTML, not the php that generates the html?

Comment: For which part? The only php I'm showing here is for the ticketid that's generated when the mySQL query results are returned.

Comment: well, what are those $row['ticket'] values in the resulting html?

Comment: As well, a select object doesn't have a .value attribute. To get the selected value, you need to use `this.options[this.selectedIndex].value`

Comment: Actually .value is working. My database is updating all the data as I prefer. I just can view the results until I refresh the page..(which is why I'm trying to use AJAX to update the appropriate DIV so that I don't have to refresh the page)

Comment: How are you telling the DB what to update?

Answer (score 1):

your HTML is wrong..

One page should have **unique** ID and you assign similar id `origassigned` to each div , because of that it always capture first div with `ID=origassigned` and update that div again & again..
instead of that use class.. or assign different id to each div..

Thanks

Comment: My issue with that, the DIV "assigned" and DIV "origassigned" are generated from a mySQL query result. Each of these groups are returned row results. I can't give them unique ID names. Even if I were to change them to classes.. There isn't a getElementByClass property so how would I select the DIVs then?

Comment: Practically its wrong to assign same id on a page.but if this is your contraint thenu can can assign `name` property and get the data by `getElementsByName`  .remember there is an `s` in function

Comment: That's a good idea, I will try that. That will get me up to standard but I'm still clueless how to tell AJAX which DIV to update. Because they will have all the same NAME.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have separate names and ids for the three selects. That way your ajax code can handle which element is being updated.